# Does the top-level-await error mean Webpack is already installed?

Tags: javascript, webpack, aws-amplify

I'm getting the error
`Module parse failed: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)`

After some research, I created a `webpack.config.js` file in the same location as my `package.json` file.  Here is the content

```js
module.exports = {
    experiments: {
        topLevelAwait: true
    }
};
```

This had no effect.  I still get the error.

Do I need to explicitly install Webpack and then create the config file?  That seems odd since the original error itself implies Webpack is already there.

Here are the dependencies from my `package.json` file. Webpack isn't there.

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/ui-react": "^4.6.2",
    "@nextui-org/react": "^1.0.0-beta.12",
    "aws-amplify": "^5.2.1",
    "next": "^13.4.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  }
```

1. Do I need to install Webpack anyway?
2. Or, if I don't need to install it, what do I need to change about the `webpack.config.js` file to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out NextJS has Webpack embedded in it. Therefore Webpack is installed.

Also, the way to enable top-level-await is to annotate the `next.config.js` file like this:

```js
module.exports = {
    webpack: (config) => {
        // this will override the experiments
        config.experiments = {...config.experiments, topLevelAwait: true};
        // this will just update topLevelAwait property of config.experiments
        // config.experiments.topLevelAwait = true
        return config;
    },
};
```